# Is there a way to zip json into rows and columns in web2py?

Tags: python, json, web2py

I have below json data

```
col = {"00:00:00:00": {"NAME":"aaa","ID":"111","DEPT":"8888","JOIN":"666","DL":333,"SNAME":"John","UPLOAD":"600","RETRY":"3","IP":"111.222.333.444"},
       "11:11:11:11:11": {"NAME":"bbb","ID":"222","DEPT":"9999","JOIN":"777","DL":222,"SNAME":"Mary","UPLOAD":"200","RETRY":"2","IP":"122.133.144.155"},
       "22:22:22:22": {"NAME":"ccc","ID":"333","DEPT":"6666","JOIN":"111","DL":333,"SNAME":"Stuart","UPLOAD":"500","RETRY":"4","IP":"199.188.177.166"}}
```

How can I use ZIP and put in rows and columns list in web2py ? 
I tried using

```
rows = zip(*col[c] for c in columns)
```

But I am not getting correct output. 
Columns should be

```
columns = ["NAME", "ID", "DEPT", "JOIN", "DL", "SNAME", "UPLOAD", "RETRY", "IP"]
```

rows are associated values in json.

I am looking to have table in below format

```
NAME, ID, DEPT, JOIN, DL, SNAME, UPLOAD, RETRY, IP
aaa   111 888   666   333 John   600     3     111.222.333.444
```

....similarly all other values associated with keys.

Comment: And what are `columns` and `col` here?

Comment: So what is the expected output?

Comment: Columns are those key inside json data like in above
Columns should be "NAME", "ID", "DEPT", "JOIN", "DL", "SNMAE", "ULOAD", "RETRY", "IP"
 and rows are corresponding values associated with above keys in columns>

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include clarifications.

Comment: Would your table be a nested list of lists perhaps?

Comment: [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean this perhaps?

```
columns = col.values()[0].keys()
zip(columns, zip(*(v.values() for v in col.values())))
```

where `col` references your dictionary and `columns` is a list produced from the keys of *one* of the nested dictionaries.

It is important that you produce `columns` from a nested dictionary, otherwise you wouldn't get the keys and values in the same order.

Demo:

```
>>> col = {"00:00:00:00":{"NAME":"aaa","ID":"111","DEPT":"8888","JOIN":"666","DL":333,"SNAME":"John","ULOAD":"600","RETRY":"3","IP":"111.222.333.444"},
... "11:11:11:11:11":{"NAME":"bbb","ID":"222","DEPT":"9999","JOIN":"777","DL":222,"SNAME":"Mary","UPLOAD":"200","RETRY":"2","IP":"122.133.144.155"},
... "22:22:22:22":{"NAME":"ccc","ID":"333","DEPT":"6666","JOIN":"111","DL":333,"SNAME":"Stuart","UPLOAD":"500","RETRY":"4","IP":"199.188.177.166"}}
>>> columns = col.values()[0].keys()
>>> zip(columns, zip(*(v.values() for v in col.values())))
[('DEPT', ('9999', '8888', '6666')), ('DL', (222, 333, 333)), ('SNAME', ('Mary', 'John', 'Stuart')), ('JOIN', ('777', '666', '111')), ('NAME', ('bbb', 'aaa', 'ccc')), ('IP', ('122.133.144.155', '600', '199.188.177.166')), ('RETRY', ('2', '111.222.333.444', '4')), ('ID', ('222', '3', '333')), ('UPLOAD', ('200', '111', '500'))]
>>> pprint(zip(columns, zip(*(v.values() for v in col.values()))))
[('DEPT', ('9999', '8888', '6666')),
 ('DL', (222, 333, 333)),
 ('SNAME', ('Mary', 'John', 'Stuart')),
 ('JOIN', ('777', '666', '111')),
 ('NAME', ('bbb', 'aaa', 'ccc')),
 ('IP', ('122.133.144.155', '600', '199.188.177.166')),
 ('RETRY', ('2', '111.222.333.444', '4')),
 ('ID', ('222', '3', '333')),
 ('UPLOAD', ('200', '111', '500'))]
```

Comment: Pieters, Thanks ! 
I feel that first answer was what I was looking for. I want to add rows and column values in list and send it to view.
Please, could you post previous suggestion ?

Comment: @Error_Coding: reverted to the first revision for you.

Comment: How could I put this in row and column. I tried

`{{=TABLE(THEAD(TR([TH(c) for c in col])),
            (TR([TD(row) for row in row)), _class = 'myTable')}}`

But not getting table in desired format

Comment: I don't know web2py all that well, sorry.